# Navigate in file list of VSCode with vim

Tags: vim, visual-studio-code

Hi I use vscode with vim extensions on Window OS

If i press Ctrl+P to display list file.
Is there any hot key to navigate in file list without arrow key?

Comment: What do you mean navigate in file? You want to use other key not arrow?

Answer (score 0):

No. It would break the functionality for the file list since it allows you to fuzzy find files. If "j" or "k" moved up and down, it would be impossible to search for files with "j" or "k" in their names.